# Cross section of $z=2x^2-y^2$

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get the cross section of the graph $z = 2x^2 - y^2$ and I have no clue where to even start. I am supposed to take the cross section at $x=0, x=-1, x=1, y=0, y=1, y=1, z=0, z=1$, and $z=-1$.

I tried taking my original code and just subbing in the values that I am supposed to take the cross section at, but that does not seem correct. My TA mentioned something about a Show function, but did not explain how it worked.

My original code:

```
Plot3D[2x^2-y^2, {x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can visualize the slices with `ParametricPlot3D`

```
GraphicsRow[
 With[{slice = #}, 
    Show[
     ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f"}, ViewVector -> {4, -7, 11}], 
     ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate[slice /@ {-1, 0, 1}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
    ] & /@ {{#, a, b} &, {a, #, b} &, {a, b, #} &}, ImageSize -> 750
 ]
```

[image]

Notice how useful the [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) function is here. Basically it allows you to "show" multiple plots within the same graphics object. You could get flashier and highlight the curves where the slices intersect the surface (try, for example, `ParametricPlot3D[{-1, y, f[-1, y]}, {y, -2, 2}]`), but I'll leave that up to you.

(I've also made use of [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/ @`) which is a very useful tool when you're working over lists, and [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html), which is a scoping construct that, among other things, can make using `Map` much clearer.)

And to get plots of the specific slices

```
plotfuns = {f[#, a] == b &, f[a, #] == b &, f[a, b] == # &};
framelabels = {{"y", "z"}, {"x", "z"}, {"x", "y"}};
plotlabels = {"f[" <> ToString[#] <> ", y]" &, 
   "f[x, " <> ToString[#] <> "]" &, "f[x, y] == " <> ToString[#] &};

GraphicsGrid[
 With[{plotinfo = #}, 
    ContourPlot[Evaluate@plotinfo[[1]][#], {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, 
       AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> plotinfo[[2]], 
       PlotLabel -> plotinfo[[3]][#]] & /@ {-1, 0, 1}] & /@ 
  Transpose[{plotfuns, framelabels, plotlabels}],
 ImageSize -> 750
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
f = Function[{x, y}, 2 x^2 - y^2]
slicePts = {-1, 0, 1}
(* slice on x: *)
Plot[f[#, y], {y, -2, 2}] & /@ slicePts
(* slice on y: *)
Plot[f[x, #], {x, -2, 2}] & /@ slicePts
(* slice on z: *)
ContourPlot[# == f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] & /@ slicePts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[2 x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> (fun), 
  Mesh -> {msh},MeshStyle -> Red], 
{fun, {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &}}, {msh, {{-1}, {0}, {1}}}]
```

[image]